# Need to store values from URL then send this values using post method

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, python-requests

I need to store some values from a GET method than send this values using the POST method in a form.

How can i do that? it is possible?

I Already get the values from GET method and works fine, but when i try to use the payload in the POST it goes wrong because the payload dict doesnt exist in the POST

```
if request.method == 'GET':
                payload = {
                    "sessId": request.GET['sessId'],
                    "userName": request.GET['userName'],
                    "sessionLifetime": SESSION_TIMEOUT,
                    "idleTimeout": IDLE_TIMEOUT,
                }

if request.method == 'POST':
    logic with the payload
    requests.post(url,payload)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need `requests.post(url,data=payload)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when GETting a url the data can be parsed from the URI.
when POSTing a url the data must be parsed from the headers.

usually you will find the POSTed data in the `'x-www-form-urlencoded'` header